# gwt uibinder ui:with - calling methods with arguments

Tags: java, gwt

I am using gwt uibinder. I want to dynamically set values to a field.
I am trying something like this

```
<ui:with field="valuesStore" type='x.y.client.ValuesStore' />
```

and the field is set with value like this

```
<g:Label text='{valuesStore.getValue}'>Name</g:Label>
```

and the ValueStore has 2 methods

```
public String getValue(String key) {
    return localizedValues.get(key);
}

public String getValue() {
    return null;
}
```

The problem is i am unable to call the getValue(key). I could only call the no-args method meaning the following is not possible

```
<g:Label text='{valuesStore.getValue('name')}'>Name</g:Label>
```

Please clarify if there is a way to achieve this where i can call a method with arguments passed to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not supported, only methods without arguments can be invoked. You are going to have to expose the `name` directly as a no args method.

Look at the documentation for [FieldReferenceConverter](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/FieldReferenceConverter.html), this describes the syntax used. You can see that there is no support for argument passing.

Comment: Thank you. Great. I would like to know if there is any alternative to achieve my purpose - set the value for a field in ui.xml by calling a java method with arg. This is easily doable in the owner java class itself but i want it to be in xml file.

Comment: I think that this still holds true, but I couldn't find the documentation of the updated GWT

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Please find it here: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/FieldReferenceConverter.html