# Alternative to uibinder I18n

Tags: gwt, localization, internationalization, uibinder

There is the Uibinder way of doing i18n as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n)
And then there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937269/gwt-uibinder-uiwith-calling-methods-with-arguments) suggestion for GWT i18n.

I am considering the alternative as I am experiencing some issues with the first solution.
I wish to know the pros and cons of both methods so I know what to choose.
Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first solution is very verbose, requires you to put localization files in specific folders and is described as [a kind of a nightmare](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4355) but it does support text with (runtime) variables. The second solution doesn't support variables in messages, but is much easier to use.

The second solution support 2 use cases. This is how they look for both solutions:

Plain text:

Solution 1:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
    ui:generateKeys="com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator"
    ui:generateLocales="default">
  <div><ui:msg key="helloWorld" description="Greeting">Hello, world.</ui:msg></div>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

Solution 2:

```
<ui:with field='i18n' type='x.y.client.i18n.MyMessages' />
....
<div><ui:text from="{i18n.helloWorld}" /></div>
```

In the solution 1 the text inside the tag will be the default text and the description is in the description attribute. In the second solution you would add that in the interface class `MyMessages` which extends `Messages`.

Static method argument:

Solution 1:

```
<th title="Gross receipts">
  <ui:attribute ui:name='title' ui:description='Tooltip text for gross column'/>
  ...
</th>
```

Solution 2:

```
<th title="{i18n.grossReceiptsTitle}">...</th>
```

Any more advanced usage of message like passing arguments is not possible with solution 2, but you can always fall back to add them in your constructor after the `initWidget` call.

Comment: UiBinder I18N really shines when you have widgets inside your messages, e.g. `<ui:msg>As a <g:TextBox ui:field="userType" />, I want to <g:TextBox ui:field="goal" />, so that <g:TextBox ui:field="reason" />.`. And with `ui:baseMessagesInterface`, it's a whole lot less of a nightmare, almost in par with the so-called "solution 2".