# Possibility of calling my static java method(and passing arguments ) in Ui binder (xml)

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt2

Is there a way pass arguments to java methods?
Inside the `Ui binder`  I imported class like 
below

```
<ui:with type="com..myproject.MyUtil" field="util"/>
```

I am calling a normal static method like

```
<g:Label text="{util.getEditInfoString}" ui:field="editInfo" />
```

I wrote my business logic in `getEditInfoString`() method and `returns string`,Which is working like a charm .

Now  I have an requirement  that need to pass one `argument(string)` to that `method` from my `binder` file .

What is the way to do that ??any hints ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no support for argument passing. only methods without arguments can be invoked

Refer [FieldReferenceConverter](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/uibinder/attributeparsers/FieldReferenceConverter.html)

**[gwt uibinder ui:with - calling methods with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937269/gwt-uibinder-uiwith-calling-methods-with-arguments)**

Comment: Thanks @tak ,I'll look for another approach now.Seems like I have to sharpen my search skills :)  Didn't find that while I am searching.